# Ubuntu 16.04.1 garbage display (hung or frozen)

Tags: graphics, display

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my Desktop (2.5gHzDualCore,2gbRAM,500HDD) successfully, but when I run or click one application, its always freezes then the display turn into garbage and hangs. I tried to restart many times but it didn't work. I get the same thing every time.

When windows 7 was installed on the same desktop it didn't hang or freeze, so what's the problem?

Comment: Have you checked you pr system? No corruption? What is your graphics card? Is everything above the recommended thingy?

Comment: Thank you for giving your time to respond. There is no graphic card (hardware) inserted in the motherboard. Im just using the onboard graphic card and the driver is nvidia. I tried linux mint cinnamon also but it came out with the same problem. Pixelated garbage display as always. What should i do? Please help.

Comment: Insert a graphics card ; the onboard one might be faulty.